# How can I make a image at edge of a layout?

Tags: android, imageview

[image]Hi I am working with android app.I am looking to create a layout as in the picture.I had created the view at the center. But I want to show the image at the corner of the layout. How can I do this ? please help me with some examples,thanks in advance :)[image]

Comment: what u want exactly please show some image what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code:-

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:background="#000000" >
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/shape_circle_red" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable -> shape_circle_red**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

use layout_alignParentRight or left or top or bottom to display the image at the corner of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_groupindicator_add" />
```